# Visual Studio Code custom snippet

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I work on a product which contains dozens of projects hierarchically organized in different directories depending on type of the project. I am using VS Code for development.

All source files need to have doc-comment header containing component name and unit name (filename base) among other information.

Each project contains JSON file which defines component name and is used in build. The component name is different from the directory where the project resides.

I have created a custom snippet similar to:

```
{
  "description": "File document comment",
  "prefix": ["file-doc-comment"],
  "body": [
    "/*---------------------------------",
    " *  COMPONENT   : {???}",
    " *  UNIT        : ${TM_FILENAME_BASE}",
    "---------------------------------"
  ]
}
```

Is it possible somehow to parse the file by executing a function or command and insert values from parsed file instead of **{???}** ? Does VS Code allows such a thing?

**EDIT**

File path would be something like `xxx/yyy/Source/zzz.h` .

JSON content would be something like:

```
{
    "name" : "aaa"
}
```

Comment: Are you applying this snippet retroactively to a bunch of existing files? I would have thought that a snippet like this would be used when creating a _new_ file, in which case the file would be empty with nothing to parse... Can you provide some example layout of the directories and a file's contents?

Comment: I will not apply snippet retroactively. Only for new files. I would like to populate fields automatically, if possible. File path does not relate to name in JSON file, but I will update the question by adding file path and JSON content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 2 extensions you can create a snippet/template that can use the content of a JSON file.

- [File Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-file-templates)
- [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable)

The JSON file **`component.json`** stored in the same folder as the file:

```json
{
  "component": {
    "name": "MyCoolServer"
  }
}
```

You can add to a template or the command `templates.pasteTemplate` the following text:

```
/*---------------------------------
 *  COMPONENT   : ${command##
                    command=extension.commandvariable.file.content##
                    args={ "fileName": "${fileDirname}/component.json",
                           "json": "content.component.name"}##}
 *  UNIT        : ${fileBasename}
 ---------------------------------*/
```

The result could be:

```
/*---------------------------------
 *  COMPONENT   : MyCoolServer
 *  UNIT        : contact.c
 ---------------------------------*/
```

If you don't want to create a separate key binding for this snippet you can use [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) to create a pick list of named commands with arguments.